# Editing the Axis on Cognos Report Studio Charts

Tags: charts, report, cognos

I need to edit the X-axis of my charts in Report Studio to something like this:

**2010 Fall Semester** --> CHANGE TO --> **2010 Fall**

**2011 Fall Semester** --> CHANGE TO --> **2011 Fall**

**2012 Fall Semester** --> CHANGE TO --> **2012 Fall**

and so on.

Basically just remove the last word.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can manually do this through the properties. I'm trying to avoid using a case statement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a replace statement on the field containing your name:

```
replace ([Column Name] , ' Semester' , '')
```

Don't forget the space between the first quote and the word Semester.

Also, if this is a naming convention you will be using elsewhere, look into working it into your time Dimension.